# Use template class in another class in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template class that I want to use in another class. The problem is that I want to use the template class without knowing the actual type.

A simple example:

```
template <class T> 
class Foo{
    private:
        T x_;
    public:
        void Foo(T);
};
```

Now, another class using `Foo`. What I would like to do is:

```
class Bar{
    private:
        Foo foo_;

    public:
        Bar(Foo);
};
```

The problem is that `Foo` requires a template argument when used inside `Bar`. It would be nice if the `Bar` class would handle `Foo` with any template argument. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `Bar` itself a *class template*:

```
template <typename T>
class Bar{
    private:
        Foo<T> foo_;

    public:
        Bar(Foo<T>);
};
```

---

Alternatively, you can *type-erase* `Foo` under a common polymorphic interface. This restricts the usage of `Foo` and introduces run-time and memory overhead.

```
struct FooBase {
    virtual ~FooBase() { }
    virtual void Xyz(int) { }  
};

template <class T> 
class Foo : FooBase {
    private:
        T x_;
    public:
        void Foo(T); 
        void Xyz(int) override 
        {
            // `T` can be used in the definition, but 
            // cannot appear in the signature of `Xyz`.
        }
};

class Bar{
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<FooBase> foo_;

    public:
        Bar(std::unique_ptr<FooBase>&&);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, your first solution is nice and simple! I was just wondering: If you have an hierarchical structure of classes where class A is used by B is used by C etc., then it is somewhat annoying to always pass along the template argument.

Comment: @beginneR: can you show an example? It's a fairly common thing which shouldn't be too annoying

Comment: Say my `Base` class takes as input a vector of `Foo` classes, but the problem is that every `Foo` in the vector has another type and I don't want one `Base` class for every type of `Foo`.

Comment: I meant 'Bar' instead of 'Base'